# При определенном запросе - обработка, при остальных - редирект (nginx)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, unix

Скажем есть сайт `site.com`

- если зайти на `site.com/user`, исполняются скрипты из `/var/www/user.com/`
- если зайти на `site.com/admin`, то из `/usr/share/admin/`

По всем остальным URL (или даже просто на site.com) редирект, скажем на яндекс.

Предполагаемый конфиг выглядит так:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com;
    root /var/www/site.com;

    location ~* /user/.+.php {
        alias /var/www/user.com/;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location ~* /admin/.+.php {
        alias /usr/share/admin/;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$ http://ya.ru/$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

Но что-то идет не так. Сразу срабатывает последнее правило на редирект.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет "входа" в какие-то `location`, то скорее всего не срабатывают регулярные выражения.

Попробуйте: `^/user/.+\.php$`.